Package minted Error: minted v3+ executable is not installed, is not added toTORY environment variable
I'm using package minted (v3.4.0 from 2024/11/17) and XeLaTeX in TeXLive 2024, Windows 10. According to the package manual, I have sucessfully intalled latexminted in Anaconda Prompt with pip install latexminted. And the Path of pygmentize has been added in Environment, see the following figure of cmd.exe,

Here is the MWE.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}[bgcolor=Beige, bgcolorpadding=0.5em]{c}
        int main() {
            printf("hello, world");
            return 0;
        }
    \end{minted}
\end{document}

After compiling with xelatex, some error appears as follows,
Package minted Error: minted v3+ executable is not installed, is not added toTORY environment variable. ^^I\end{minted}
Package minted Error: Missing definition for highlighting style "default" (mistyle. ^^I\end{minted}
Package minted Error: Cannot highlight code (minted executable is unavailable or disabled); attempting to typeset without highlighting. ^^I\end{minted}

The minted manual said that -shell-escape is not necessary after TeXLive 2024. But I also try it with
xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex 

while the following error appears,
Package minted Error: minted v3+ executable is not installed or is not added ut setting a TEXMF_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY environment variable. ^^I\end{minted}

Why do these errors occur and how to fix them?
======updated======
I also have tried pip install latexminted, see the following figure. The same errors also occur.


Does texlive on windows include latexminted? On unix, all my problems vanished as soon I uninstalled the pip version so minted can find the one from texlive.

The latexminted is installed by myself. Before I install it, there also exist errors when compile the MWE.

The workaround to this issue in Windows 10 and Windows 11 (both tested under TeXLive and MiKTeX) is to install latexminted from pip
pip install latexminted

For some reason, I needed  to run that twice in Windows 10 under MIKTEX to work.

I have installed latexminted by pip and pygmentize is normally run in command line. But also occur errors.

Do it in normal cmd prompt. Not anaconda

I just try it in normal cmd.exe. The same errors also occur.

I tried in one of my laptops and it is not working with xelatex. Could you try with lualatex instead, to discard a compiler specific issue?

Oh, I just tried it and the same error still occurred. I also tried it with -shell-escape.

Thanks @xiao-lishun, it is really key advisory: "perform installation in cmd", not in anaconda. Now minted working for me in TeXworks (Windows).
